# Java date parsing without separators?

Tags: java

In my program i am parsing a string date(frmDateStr) with separators as below and getting fromDate 
which I use for my further comparisons.

```
String frmDateStr = "12/25/2013";
Date fromDate = formatter.parse(frmDateStr);
```

Now if i pass `frmDateStr = "12252013" or "122513"(2 digit year)` i want to get the same result.
But i got `parse exception.`

So please let me know how to get date value while the string is without separators and short year?

Thanks in advance

Yash

Comment: You have to build different formatter for different Date format.

Comment: Change the formatter...

Answer (score 3):

Use this code, it will help

```
String dateFormat = "MMddyyyy";
if (dateString.indexOf("/") != -1)
{
    dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
}
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
System.out.print(formatter.parse(dateString));
```

your input is `dateString`

Comment: This solution is fine. but the dateString entered by user may be of any locale. so it can contain '/' or '-' or any thing. how to deal that?

Comment: Make if check to validate all the possibles :-)

Answer (score 1):

As the other Answers say, you must define a formatter that fits your data.

## java.time

Java 8 and later come bundled with the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)). These new classes supplant the old java.util.Date/.Calendar & java.text.SimpleDateFormat.

Also, java.time includes a class [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) to represent simply a date only without time-of-day and time zone, as you have in the Question.

```
String input = "12252013";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMddyyyy" );
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( input , formatter );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "localDate : " + localDate );
```

When run.

> localDate : 2013-12-25

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by vapa1115 on 9/27/2018.
 */
public class UtmUtil {
    public static String getSourceAddress(String sourceAddressValue) {
       if(sourceAddressValue==null) {
           Random r = new Random();
           sourceAddressValue = r.nextInt(256) + "." + r.nextInt(256) + "." + r.nextInt(256) + "." + r.nextInt(256);
       }else{
           Random r = new Random();
           int ind = sourceAddressValue.lastIndexOf(".");
           String randomValue=r.nextInt(256)+"";
           if(randomValue.length()>3){
               randomValue=randomValue.substring(0,2);
           }
           sourceAddressValue= new StringBuilder(sourceAddressValue).replace(ind, ind+1,"."+randomValue).toString();
        }
        return sourceAddressValue;

    }
    public static void main(String sd[]){
        getSourceAddress("192.168.0");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create your own `SimpleDateFormat` instance and use it to read date from a string:

All necessary information can be found here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html